# CQRS and Domain Events

Tags: cqrs, domain-events

CQRS has got me into thinking mode.. I am tryinng to start a new project with CQRS ideas. The main things that I like is
1) the separation of Query and Command. Our Domain queries have been a problem.
2) Using Event Storage for Audit - I wont be using it for Replay - AT least not now.

I am good with the query side and I still have some questions on Domain Events

If a Command  results in updation of Multiple Aggregates Roots( Ex. Order and OrderDetail)  I will have the  them scoped under UnitofWork ( transactional). Now each domain is responsible for publishing events when a change takes place to its state.

let us say the command changes 3 orderDetail records. Each OrderDetail will publish 2 Events. In the end we have 6 events .

a) If I publish the events as soon as I have made the changes to the domain object ( but not committed the transaction)  how do I reverse the events that have been published (and may have been consumed by subscribers)

- What I can think of is to hold the events to be published in a list 'under the same  unit of work scope' and once the committ on transaction has been called, store it and  publish it . Does this sound something one would do.

b)  If the changes in OrderDetail requires that some change also take place in Order Aggregate Root then
    i) Should I base those changes  by handling the events published by  OrderDetail Aggregate ? For ex. let us say two Order Detail were removed. This makes Order status from "preferred" to "Not preferred" . 
    ii) What if the Event errors and does not update  order state - If order remains preferred then it gets shipped in 2 days.

**Adding another question**
c)  Are "Domain events are the source of all application state changes" or are they "Result of all application state changes"

Thank you in Advance,

The Mar

Comment: I'd advise to post the questions like this to Google Group on DDD/CQRS. There are more practitioners there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

a) you should not publish events until your transaction is commited, an event reprsent something that **has happened**, and hence the reason why they are all named in pass tense (eg OrderClearedEvent). Also in the case that you have to "revert" an event, you should take a corrective action, ie you dont erase the event, you must trigger a new event that corrects the effects of the event you want to revert

b) it seems that this is more of a problem on how you are modelling you entities and commands that anything else. I cant think of a reason why OrderDetail would be an AggregateRoot, but I dont know your domain...

c)  Commands will result in at least one event being published

Hope this helps :) As Rinat said, the google group is the best place for asking questions, also have a look at cqrsinfo.com and the sample code from github.com/MarkNijhof/Fohjin and github.com/gregoryyoung/m-r

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have been using DDD/CQRS and NCQRS  google groups as Rinat mentioned. A lot of good discussion there.

Comment: Axon is a good source of information and examples if you're in the Java world. https://github.com/AxonFramework